# customsd service does not hit server for GetSessionId call

Tags: sonos

This is essentially a duplicate of [Can not add account for custom Sonos service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31881695/can-not-add-account-for-custom-sonos-service), but there's no accepted answer and I am not able to add a comment to ask if they ever resolved their issue.

I've inherited a project and am trying to add the development service. I've configured it via /customsd.htm, set the header policy to Session ID, have both secure and insecure endpoints working.

When I go to add the channel, I see the request for strings.xml. However, I never see any requests come in for getSessionId. Meanwhile the SONOS reports "Account Not Found. ***** server did not recognize your login information." I am able to make the request with SoapUI, and I get a valid response.

If it's worth mentioning, I am in SONOS' beta program and am on version 6.2, build 31926010 (Mac desktop app).

UPDATE:

While I'm not sure there's anything useful here, looking at logs at `[deviceIP]:1400/support/aggregate`, I see the following. Note that the redacted URL and IP do resolve. IP is for a loadbalancer, URL is behind it.

```
Feb 28 11:07:42 Sonos[84168] <![CDATA[<]]>Error<![CDATA[>]]>: (SCLib) dns(1): [redacted URL] -<![CDATA[>]]> [redacted IP]
Feb 28 11:07:42 Sonos[84168] <![CDATA[<]]>Error<![CDATA[>]]>: (SCLib) control_client(1): getSessionId failed, res = 1000, tvStart = 1456679262 s 250163 us, m_tvConnectDone = 1456679282 s 250162 us, m_tvDone = 1456679302 s 250162 us, tvNow = 1456679262 s 509982 us
Feb 28 11:07:42 Sonos[84168] <![CDATA[<]]>Error<![CDATA[>]]>: (SCLib) soap(1):  - param username = [redacted username]
```

UPDATE #2:

I inspected the packets via Wireshark, and behavior of the production service and development one seem the same except that for the production service, the controller / my computer kicks off a POST request to the Sonos before the server hangs up. That process, outlined in red in the attached image, does not occur for the customsd service.

[image: Wireshark output of GetSessionId attempt]

I also experimented with using the production service endpoints in the customsd configuration, but that request failed in the same manner. FWIW, all ssl_validation tests pass just fine, as do various content tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For want of a trailing slash...

I finally sorted this, and it was incredibly minor. In the customsd configuration, my endpoint urls did not have a trailing slash. Adding them made it all work.

I finally realized this when I decrypted the calls the controller made to the server for both the production service and my customsd service registered to the production endpoints. The call made by the customsd service was getting back the load balancer's 400 error. The only difference between the calls were the headers, specifically:

Production service: `POST / HTTP/1.1`

Dev service : `POST  HTTP/1.1`

LB properly said the call was invalid. Adding the trailing slash made it all work.

For what it's worth, I'm pretty sure the URLs without trailing slashes worked both via curl and, I believe, via SoapUI. The Sonos controller requires them, however.