# Sonos: service does not hit server for GetSessionId call from time to time

Tags: sonos

I have a music service added to Sonos in production,

I received a complaint about our Sonos Service (in production) of a user who can not login from time to time (GetSessionID call). A bit later, everything works fine. When I manually perform a GetSessionId call to the server, I get a valid answer. And by looking at the server logs when the problem arises, I see no request for GetSessionId entering our server. So normally, everything works fine (our service is in production, so it works), but sometimes the GetSessionID call is not fired to the server in my opinion.

I can recall that I had this similar problem a couple of times in the past. My previous post never got any answer ([Can not add account for custom Sonos service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31881695/can-not-add-account-for-custom-sonos-service)).

Is there a way to see if a GetSessionId is sent from the Sonos controller or device?

I contacted Sonos, but their answer to post this problem on stackoverflow. 
Can anyone help me with this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the problem happening when the user is adding the account for the first time, or when `getSessionId` is called when the session has expired?

If you could give some more information about the specific nature of the failure the user is seeing, it may help us to narrow down whether `getSessionId` is the culprit, or something else.

Comment: I only had the problem when I wanted to add my account for the Tunify service. So when I had to enter the username and password to add the service.

Comment: If this is easily recreatable, make it happen again, then capture a diag from you desktop or mobile Sonos app. Forward that diag to our customer care folks, and they'll be able to examine it to look for possible issues.

Comment: Ok, it is not recreatable, but when the issue happens again, I will send the diagnostics information to customer care. I did not know this was possible. Thanks